# Handling multiple SSH keys/configs

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two SSH keys 'personal' and 'work'.

With them I need to connect to a service: `user@service.com`.

The keys are linked to two accounts on service.com, however in SSH they both have to use the same user 'user'. Thus I can't use `~/.ssh/config` and 'Host's to route the two keys to the correct accounts. As a result, I put the 'work' key into `~/.ssh/config` using `Host`, and comment it out when wanting to do stuff with my 'personal' key.

My question is, is there a better way to handle this?

When I interact with that service, I will `source somefile.sh` anyway so having some environment variable in there to handle the routing would be ideal, but I can't find a way to change, for example, the ssh config file path, using environment variables.

I don't use `ssh` directly but rather through a 3rd party tool.

Is there such a variable?

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have two entries in `~/.ssh/config` and have whatever settings you need:

```
Host work
User workid
HostName service.com

Host personal
User homeid
HostName service.com
```

Then you can do `ssh work` and `ssh personal`.

Basically the trick is: the `Host` part does not have to be a real DNS host name, it can be whatever you want.

Comment: I should have added: I can't actually use ssh directly. It's done through a 3rd party command line tool.

Comment: Does that mean you have no control over the command?  Because you could also use `ssh -F myfile` to override `$HOME/.ssh/config`

Comment: This is the tool I'm using: https://github.com/epio/epio-client/, specifically this bit of code: https://github.com/epio/epio-client/blob/master/epio/commands/run.py

So I cannot directly modify the ssh party, but the environment of it.

Comment: You could modify `$HOME` but that's going to cause its own problems.  I recommend changing that python code to use `ssh -F` if you set something in the environment.

Comment: just to clarify, ``-F /path/to/other/ssh-config``? As in -F points to the config file? EDIT: Nevermind, did the ``man ssh`` thing and found out. Thanks

Comment: Right!  See the ssh man page for more.